# Why might concat not be a function, even with two strings?

Tags: javascript

I am generating a dropdown menu and I would like each option in the dropdown menu to be labelled with two strings (product name and company name) and have a serial number as a value attribute. These are each obtained from JSON (contained in a variable called `list`).

Here is a sample record from the JSON:

```
[
    {
        'code': '01234567', 
        'company': 'SAMPLE COMPANY', 
        'name': 'SAMPLE PRODUCT'
    }
]
```

This should be presented in the HTML like so:

`<option value="01234567">SAMPLE PRODUCT [SAMPLE COMPANY]</option>`

My Javascript is as follows:

```
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
    opt.setAttribute("value", list[i]["code"]);
    var product = list[i]["name"];
    var company = list[i]["company"];
    opt.innerHTML = product.concat(" [", company, "]");
}
```

However, this fails with "Uncaught TypeError: product.concat is not a function". I've checked the data type for `product` and `company` and they are both strings in all instances.

What else might be causing this type error?

Comment: You could use template literals like `opt.innerHTML = \`${product} [${company}]\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// product is string type, just join them with "+"
// concat is a method of array type
opt.innerHTML = product + " [" + company + "]";
// tempalte string in ES6
opt.innerHTML = `${product} [${company}]`;
```

Comment: I did not realise that concat was just for arrays. Many thanks - that's working now :-)

Comment: @EysteinThanisch `.concat()` isn't just for arrays, it also [works for strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). Wondering how you checked the types of `product` and `company` - I'm not getting an error with the code you provided

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as

```
opt.innerHTML = `${product} [${company}]`;
```

```js
const list = [{
  'code': '01234567',
  'company': 'SAMPLE COMPANY',
  'name': 'SAMPLE PRODUCT'
}]

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
  opt.setAttribute("value", list[i]["code"]);
  var product = list[i]["name"];
  var company = list[i]["company"];
  opt.innerHTML = `${product} [${company}]`;
  document.body.appendChild(opt)
}
```

Comment: That also works. Thanks (and +1)!